# access to object arrasy and values with loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a problem with handling the access to my object array values, I've tried using different forms of loops, trying to get the values with forEach, includes, tried to use the object properties but I jest end up with spaghetti code and I can manage test if th values exist but if they dont they are also passed.

```
var target;

var itemValue;

function item_obj(name, type, exists) {
    this.name   = name;
    this.type   = type;
    this.exists = exists;
}

function getItemValue(itm) {

    var gm_obj = game_obj[0].item[0].name,
        i, values = [];

    console.log('getItemValue: testing:', itm);

    for (var i in gm_obj.length) {

        if(gm_obj[i].includes(itm)) {

            itm = gm_obj[i];
    console.log(itm);
        } else {

            itm = null;
        }
    }

    if (itm != null) {
        itm = new item_obj(itm, 'item', true);
        console.log('getItemValue: found:', itm);

  document.getElementById('cout').innerHTML = 'found item' + itm;

        return itm;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the code should output the target as an object so I can us the values later, I've tried separate variables too but it seems like the loop only returns the first value.

this works but returning false does not. it should set the item exists to false so I can pass it through a similar function until I find the type and use a switch statement to treat it accordingly.

here is a pen :
https://codepen.io/silconsystem/pen/oNXoBJo?editors=1111

and here is the whole thing, I'm more ahead in the development branch.

This is kicking my ass, can anyone give me some pointers?

Cheers Rob..

Comment: `for...in...` is for objects and not arrays (and especially not for numbers (`var i in gm_obj.length`)

Comment: So what is the proper way of handling, seperate arrays work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many aspects to polish in your approach, but regarding the search function itself:

```
var gm_obj = game_obj[0].item[0].name,
    i, values = [];
```

gm_obj is an array of arrays:

```
name: 
[
  ["nothing"],["potion"],["ether"],["revive"],["helmet"],
  ["coins"], ["medals"],["crown"],["robes"]
]
```

gm_obj.length is 1, therefore `for (var i in gm_obj.length)` means nothing.

I believe your previous attempt was

```
for(var i=0; i<gm_obj.length; i++) {
    // check gm_obj[i]
}
```

Anyway, you could iterate through the names  using `for...of`

```
for (var obj of gm_obj) {
  // obj is [nothing], then [potion], then etc...
  // for example:
  if(["medals"].includes(itm)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

That's checking for exact match. If that's ok, the assignement you do

```
 itm = obj; // in your code, itm = gm_obj[i]
```

Turns `itm` from string to array. I don't believe that's your goal. It should be

```
 itm = obj[0];  // still a string.
```

Further in the code, if you got a match in one loop, and nothing in the next, you wipe the found value:

```
    } else {
        itm = null;
    }
```

You should have a `break`

```
   if(obj.includes(itm)) {
     itm = obj[0];
     break;
   }
```

Or use a temporary variable to store the result. Initialize it as null, so you don't need an `else`

```
  let result=null;
  for(obj of gm_obj) {
    if(obj.includes(itm)) {
      result = obj[0];
    }
  }
```

If it's fine to skip the other elements once there's a match, just return:

```
   if(obj.includes(itm)) {
     itm = obj[0];
     return new item_obj(itm, 'item', true);
   }
```

Finally, I believe this is just a POC, because your onclick handler doesn't store the search result.

```
submitBtn.onclick = function(event) {
  target = textBox.value;

  getItemValue(target); // not storing

  document.getElementById('cout').innerHTML = target;

}
```

---

As the others have told you, you need to work with data that fits your use case. If you have no control over it source, transform it. (mapping and or reducing), because I believe your end goal is to get an object that represent each item attribute. Therefore, I would work with a game object like:

```
let  game_obj = {
  item: 
    [ 

      {name:"nothing", description:"none", game:"none", url:'#'},
      {name:"potion", description:"small boost", game:"HP +10", url:'#'},
      {name:"ether", description:"MP boost", game:"MP +10", url:'#'},
      {name:"revive", description:"alive", game:"HP +100", url:'#'},
      {name:"helmet", description:"protect head", game:"evd +3", url:'#'},
      {name:"coins", description:"player coin", game:"coins +10", url:'#'},
      {name:"medals", description:"luck plus", game:"luc +5", url:'#'},
      {name:"crown", description:"strenght plus", game:"str +5", url:'#'},
      {name:"robes", description:"strenght plus", game:"str +1", url:'#'},
    ]
  };
```

And then perform the search like

```
for(obj of game_obj.item) {
  if(obj.name.includes(itm) {
     // found matching obj
  }
}
```

It's way simpler to understand at first sight. Here's my solution.

```js
let  game_obj = 
  {
    item: 
    [ 
      
          {name:"nothing", description:"none", game:"none", url:'#'},
          {name:"potion", description:"small boost", game:"HP +10", url:'#'},
          {name:"ether", description:"MP boost", game:"MP +10", url:'#'},
          {name:"revive", description:"alive", game:"HP +100", url:'#'},
          {name:"helmet", description:"protect head", game:"evd +3", url:'#'},
          {name:"coins", description:"player coin", game:"coins +10", url:'#'},
          {name:"medals", description:"luck plus", game:"luc +5", url:'#'},
          {name:"crown", description:"strenght plus", game:"str +5", url:'#'},
          {name:"robes", description:"strenght plus", game:"str +1", url:'#'},
        ]
    };
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var target;

var itemValue;
var list = document.getElementById('list'),
 cout=document.getElementById('cout'),
 submitBtn = document.getElementById('button'),
 textBox = document.getElementById('input');

function item_obj(attributes, type='', exists=false) {
  let {
     name, description,game,url 
    }=attributes;
    this.name  = name;
  this.description  = description;
  this.game  = game;
  this.url  = url;
  this.type  = type;
  this.exists = exists;
 }

function getItemValue(itm) {

  var gm_obj = game_obj.item,
   i, values = [], foundvalue=null;
   
      list.innerHTML = '';// gm_obj.join(', ');
    console.log('getItemValue: testing:', itm);
   
  for (var obj of gm_obj) {
      let resultMsg=`${obj.name}: nope`,
          span=document.createElement('span');
         console.log({obj});
     if(obj.name.includes(itm)) {
        resultMsg=`found item: <b>${obj.name}</b>`;
        
        cout.innerHTML = resultMsg;
        span.className='found'
        span.innerHTML=resultMsg;
        list.appendChild(span);
        return new item_obj(obj,'item',true);
   }
      span.innerHTML=resultMsg;
      list.appendChild(span);
  }
    return false;
 } 



//itemValue = new item_obj(target, 'item', true);




submitBtn.onclick = function(event) {
  target = textBox.value;
  console.log({target});
  cout.innerHTML = `searching for: ${target}... `;
  window.setTimeout(()=>{
     itemValue=getItemValue(target);
     console.log(itemValue);
},1000);
  
  
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sulphur+Point&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 20px;
  background: #888;
  font-family: 'Sulphur Point';
  
}
#list span {
flex-grow: 0;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 2px 5px;
    color: #000;
    background: #ccc;
}
#list span.found {
   border:2px solid #090;
   color:#080;background:#333
}
#input {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  border:4px solid #365683;
}

#list {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
    border: 7px solid #654;
    border-radius: 12px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 165px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

#button {
  border: 4px solid #567;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#button:hover {
  border: 4px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
#button:active {  
  border: 4px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  font-weigth: bold;
}

#out {
  display:flex;
  font-family: 'Sulphur Point';
  color: #fff;
  border: 7px solid #654;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #000;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.column div,.column button,.column input {
  display:inline-flex;
}

container {
  display:flex;
  align-items:middle;
}
.column {
  
  flex-grow:0 1;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <div class="column">
<input type="text" id="input"></input>
<button id="button">submit</button>
<div id="out">
  <span id="cout"></span>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="column" id="list"></div>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues , **First** of all as Andreas pointed out that you are using the for loop wrong,for this scenario i would suggest using a `forEach` loop to iterate
**Second** of all you are setting the `itm` to `null` inside the loop.so the `itm` would be set to null if it doesn't match the last item.So what i have done is create a `found` variable and set to `true` if the `itm` is found and returned `false` if it hasn't ,hope this resolves the issue,

(i have added `alert` so that you could see if the item was found or not)

```js
let game_obj = [
  {
    item: [
      {
        name: [
          ["nothing"],
          ["potion"],
          ["ether"],
          ["revive"],
          ["helmet"],
          ["coins"],
          ["medals"],
          ["crown"],
          ["robes"]
        ]
      },
      {
        description: [
          ["none"],
          ["small boost"],
          ["MP boost"],
          ["alive"],
          ["protect head"],
          ["player coin"],
          ["luck plus"],
          ["strenght plus"],
          ["strenght plus"]
        ]
      },
      {
        game: [
          ["none"],
          ["HP +10"],
          ["MP +10"],
          ["HP +100"],
          ["evd +3"],
          ["coins +10"],
          ["luc +5"],
          ["str +5"],
          ["str +1"]
        ]
      },
      {
        url: [["#"], ["#"], ["#"], ["#"], ["#"], ["#"], ["#"], ["#"], ["#"]]
      }
    ]
  }
];
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var target;

var itemValue;

function item_obj(name, type, exists) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.exists = exists;
}

function getItemValue(itm) {
  //   console.log(game_obj);
  var gm_obj = game_obj[0].item[0].name,
    i,
    values = [];

  //   console.log("getItemValue: testing:", itm);
  let found = false;
  gm_obj.forEach(function(gm_item) {
    if (gm_item.toString().includes(itm)) {
      itm = gm_item;
      found = true;
    }
  });

  if (!found) {
    alert("Not Found");
    return false;
  }

  if (found) {
    alert("\'"+itm + "\' includes the provided text");
    itm = new item_obj(itm, "item", true);

    // console.log("getItemValue: found:", itm);

    document.getElementById("cout").innerHTML = "found item" + itm;

    return itm;
  }
}
itemValue = new item_obj(target, "item", true);
// console.log(itemValue);

var submitBtn = document.getElementById("button");
var textBox = document.getElementById("input");

submitBtn.onclick = function(event) {
  target = textBox.value;

  getItemValue(target);

  document.getElementById("cout").innerHTML = target;
};
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sulphur+Point&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 20px;
  background: #888;
  font-family: "Sulphur Point";
}

#input {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 4px solid #365683;
}

#list {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 87px;
  border: 7px solid #654;
  border-radius: 12px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  color: #fff;
}

#button {
  border: 4px solid #567;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#button:hover {
  border: 4px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
#button:active {
  border: 4px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  font-weigth: bold;
}

#out {
  font-family: "Sulphur Point";
  color: #fff;
  border: 7px solid #654;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #000;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="input"></input>
<button id="button">submit</button>
<div id="out">
  <span id="cout"></span>
</div>
<div id="list"></div>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure doesn't accurately model your domain. I say that because it does not communicate what it is modelling.

You should write out a clear specification of the exact questions that you want the data structure to answer, and that will give you the shape of it.

From your code, what I get is:

> Given the name of an item, check to see if the item exists in the collection. If it does, construct a new object with the name of the item, and the type "item"

In that case, your data structure is a flat array of names.

You take a name, then filter the name array to see if there are any elements with that name.

Here is a version that works for the first thing that your code and data communicate that you are trying to do:

```
const game_obj = [
    {
        item: 
        [   
            {
                name: 
                [
                    "nothing",
                    "potion",
                    "ether",
                    "revive",
                    "helmet",       
                    "coins",    
                    "medals",
                    "crown",
                    "robes"
                ]
            },
            {
                description:
                [
                    ["none"],
                    ["small boost"],
                    ["MP boost"],
                    ["alive"],
                    ["protect head"],       
                    ["player coin"],    
                    ["luck plus"],
                    ["strenght plus"],
                    ["strenght plus"]
                ]
            },
            {
                game:
                [
                    ["none"],
                    ["HP +10"],
                    ["MP +10"],
                    ["HP +100"],
                    ["evd +3"],     
                    ["coins +10"],  
                    ["luc +5"],
                    ["str +5"],
                    ["str +1"]
                ]
            },
            {
                url:
                [
                    ["#"],
                    ["#"],
                    ["#"],
                    ["#"],
                    ["#"],
                    ["#"],
                    ["#"],
                    ["#"],
                    ["#"]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var target;

var itemValue;

function item_obj(name, type, exists) {
        this.name   = name;
        this.type   = type;
        this.exists = exists;
    }

function getItemValue(itm) {
    const names = game_obj[0].item[0].name

        console.log('getItemValue: testing:', itm);
    const exists = names.filter(name => name === itm)
    const result = exists.length > 0 ? exists[0] : null

        if (!result) {
      return false
    }

  const item = new item_obj(result, 'item', true);
  console.log('getItemValue: found:', item);

  document.getElementById('cout').innerHTML = 'found item' + item;

  return item;

    }   
itemValue = new item_obj(target, 'item', true);
console.log(itemValue);

var submitBtn = document.getElementById('button');
var textBox = document.getElementById('input');

submitBtn.onclick = function(event) {
  target = textBox.value;

  getItemValue(target);

  document.getElementById('cout').innerHTML = target;

}
```

Notice how the array is flattened. You had an array of arrays with a single element.

I am guessing, however, that the question you want it to answer is:

> Given the name of an item, check to see if the item exists in the collection. If it does, construct a new object with the name of the item, and the type "item", and the properties of that item.

That data structure is an array of objects.

As an example:

```
const ItemData = [
  {
     name: 'potion',
     description: 'strength plus',
     game: 'STR +5',
     url: '#'
  },
  {
     name: 'revive',
     description: 'small boost',
     game: 'HP +10',
     url: '#'
  }
]
```

But you should start with a clear description in plain *and* precise language of what you want to do, because that description is pseudo-code.

I think if you look carefully, you'll find that you are ending up with spaghetti because *your description of the problem that you are setting out to solve* is spaghetti to start with.

Here is how you get an item from that data structure by name:

```
const ItemData = [
  {
     name: 'potion',
     description: 'strength plus',
     game: 'STR +5',
     url: '#'
  },
  {
     name: 'revive',
     description: 'small boost',
     game: 'HP +10',
     url: '#'
  }
]

// Given a name, return the item matching that name, or null
function getItem(itemName) {
  if (!itemName) {
    return null
  }
  const matchingItem = ItemData.filter(item => item.name === itemName)
  return matchingItem.length > 0 ? matchingItem[0] : null
}
```

See, I started with a clean statement of the problem that I want my code to solve. The data structure becomes obvious, and the code to work with it minimal and clean - because the data structure is optimized for it.

Here is a refactor of the Array.filter that lifts the predicate function out of it:

```
  const hasMatchingName = name => item => item.name === name
  const matchingItem = ItemData.filter(hasMatchingName(itemName))
```

In this case, if every item needs `type: "item"` as a property, you could either add it to the data, or else add it inline, like this:

```
// Given a name, return the item matching that name, or null
function getItem(itemName) {

  if (!itemName) {
    return null
  }
  const hasMatchingName = name => item => item.name === name

  const matchingItem = ItemData.filter(hasMatchingName(itemName))

  return matchingItem.length > 0 
    ? makeItemObject(matchingItem[0]) 
    : null
}

function makeItemObject(itemData) {
  return {...itemData, type: "item" }
}
```

If you get your data from somewhere else, and it has a hideous structure, then you have one step to transform it to the model that you need to answer your questions, and *then* you write the code to answer those questions, as a separate concern.

But you always start with a clear description of the outcome, and work backward from there.

Another couple of points:

- Don't create a massive indented block that the end says `else { return }` - instead, exit early. It reduces the indentation, and you don't have to read past all the code to figure out (for example in my code there) that if there is no name passed in, we just exit.
- Always use `const`. The only time you have to use a variable is when you have an actual variable that you have to be responsible for. But that is very rare. Everything in this code is a constant. Even the user's query is a constant. They ask for `an item` and the item that they are asking for does not change during the execution of the code.

Comment: Okay so every item is an object itself? I was thinking to make an array of each property so I can access them with an index number.

Comment: You would only use a data structure like that if items shared lots of properties, or you wanted to do combinations. Even then, it increases the complexity of both the data and the code. You are best off starting with the simplest, most direct expression of what you are modelling.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone,  you've  given some food for thought but I get my mistakes. Im gonna do some restructduring of the object array

Comment: The whole idea is creating a similar object array where I have multiple objects that all have these 4 properties; name, description, game-event, url(img) and that I can get test the user input to get a type i.e: item, weapon, npc and room object. Then use this value to handle them with a switch. I thought if I matched the item name than I'd convert it into an object holding the name, type and exist flag for further handling.

Comment: If anyone is interested here's the whole project, Its just a study project but any feedback on how to improve things is more than welcome !https://github.com/silconsystem/adventureJS/tree/development

Comment: Key lookup is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using the help of all of you I found a solution and learned a bit more. 
I made the objects more uniform and carry a type property instead of putting them in a named array wich made the search logic the same for all the types and created a small function iterating over the arrays and their name props, thus cutting out a lot of crappy code.

thats the object:

```
const game_objects = [          
{
    item: 
    [
        {
         name: "item",
         description: "player",
         game: "HP - 0",
         url: "../img/weapons/nothing.png",
         type: "item",
         handler: "player"
        },....
    ];
```

and the function:

```
// find the second string argument and set type
function findObject(arr, itm) {

    var found;
    console.log('findObject: searching for:',itm);

    for(let i in arr) {
        for (let j in arr[i])
            if (arr[i][j].name.includes(itm)) {

            found = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    itm = found;
    return itm;
}
```

this was my scratchpad for this problem

https://codepen.io/silconsystem/pen/oNXoBJo?editors=0001

the object is a part of a text input handle used like: "take potion" and added to player inventory if found and it is put in a fixed div where if objects are added we can scroll with mousewheel or keys 1 2 3 4 to focus and use cursor keys

Github:
https://github.com/silconsystem/adventureJS [development/workstation-dev]

Again thanks for everyones time !